# what was the fundamental reason that Erdogan had been able to defeat secularists in the country?

Tags: turkey, recep-tayyip-erdogan

Secularists ruled Turkey for a long period of time.

Why did they gradually lose control of Turkey's politics?

What has been the root cause of their influence gradually waned?

Comment: Do you have any references to indicate to your question to enlighten people's understanding